# Facebook registerCallback not being called on some specific device( for example motorola Edge 30 Ultra)

Tags: facebook

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(requireActivity())
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

    LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY)
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(requireParentFragment(),callbackManager, (Arrays.asList("public_profile","email")))
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, object :
        FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult) {
            Log.d("facebook_tag","ok3")
            Log.d("TAG", "Success Login")
            val request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
            ) { `object`, response ->
                Log.d("TAG", `object`.toString())
                val first_name = `object`!!.getString("first_name")
                val last_name = `object`.getString("last_name")
                var emailid:String=""
                if(`object`.length() == 4 )
                    emailid=`object`.getString("email")

                val name = "$first_name $last_name"
                val id = `object`.getString("id")

       


            }
            val parameters = Bundle()
            parameters.putString("fields", "first_name,last_name,email,id")
            request.parameters = parameters
            request.executeAsync()
```

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

```
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
```

}

```
        override fun onCancel() {

            requireActivity().showToast("Login Cancelled")
        }

        override fun onError(exception: FacebookException) {
            requireActivity().showToast(exception.message.toString())
        }

    })
```

Trying to login with facebook but registerCallback is not calling on some specific device like Motorola Edge 30 Ulltra.